# Lazy loaded script path not working properly in production build

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

when I try to take final production build with lazy load feature. All other scripts are working fine but only lazy-loaded script path not working properly.  I need all scripts in the **scripts** folder. I have added **deployUrl": "/scripts/"**, but for lazy loaded files the folder path **scripts**, not pretending. The lazy loading scripts are not prepending /scripts/ path.

Comment: can you give an minimal stackblitz?

Comment: for example - All other scripts are loading test.com/p/scripts/1.js
But Lazy loaded scripts path is test.com/p/lazy.js

Comment: shouldn't it be test.com/p/scripts/lazy.js?

Comment: Finally, I have resolved this issue  - The solution is, Within tsconfig.json we need to setup baseUrl. Then this will work fine.